# KK-theoretical proof of Atiyah-Singer index theorem

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, index-theory, kk-theory

Does anyone know of any detailed proof of the Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem using KK-theory/ Kasparov products? References to any papers and textbooks are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A standard reference is A. Connes and G. Skandalis paper http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/longitudinal.pdf. The paper does the index theorem for foliations as well but you can only read the first 3 chapters.

Answer (score 3):

I find the proof in the recent paper of Kasparov

> G. Kasparov. Elliptic and transversally elliptic index theory from the
>   viewpoint of KK-theory. J. Noncommut. Geom., 10(4):1303–1378, 2016

difficult but understandable. There are certainly more details than in Kasparov's Inventiones paper.